# Pegar linha selecionada do dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Tenho uma `dataTable` com os dados de na frente de cada dado um botão, quando eu clico no botão um `dialog` é aberto para que eu possa fazer uma edição nesses dados, porém não consigo pegar o objeto que foi selecionado para passar como parâmetro pro método que faz a edição.

Como que eu consigo pegar a `linha(objeto)` selecionada da tabela ao clicar no botão editar?

Estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
<p:dialog header="Pausar Atividade" widgetVar="dlg3"
                modal="true" height="300" width="700">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="width:100%;margin-top:20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">      
                    <p:outputLabel value="Motivo" />
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="30" counter="display1"
                            maxlength="255" counterTemplate="{0} Caracteres Restantes."
                            autoResize="false" style="width:70%" value="#{tarefaBean.tarefa.comentario}" />
                        <br />
                        <h:outputText id="display1" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="Pausar Tarefa" style="margin-left:25%;margin-top:20px;width:50%" actionListener="#{tarefaBean.pausarTarefa}" update=":msgGlobal: frmPrin"/>
</p:dialog>
```

O botão na dataTable:

```
<p:column headerText="Ações" style="text-align:center">
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-check" title="Finalizar"  onclick="PF('dlg4').show();" />
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pause" title="Pausar" onclick="PF('dlg3').show();" />
</p:column>
```

Método no bean:

```
public void pausarTarefa(){
    try {
        tarefa.setStatus("Pausado");
        tarefa.setDataFim(new Date());

        TarefaDAO tarefaDAO = new TarefaDAO();
        tarefaDAO.editar(tarefa);   
        FacesUtil.adicionarMsgInfo("Solicitação Enviada com Sucesso");

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao Enviar Solicitação!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma melhor prática de programação seria deixar o processamento na parte do *Bean*, que é responsável pelo controle dos atributos no front-end. Lembre-se sempre disto. É importante frisar que as páginas JSF/JSP devem possuir o mínimo de regras possíveis para facilitar na hora da manutenção do código.

### Vamos a solução:

Na sua tela, use a propriedade **action** no seu commandButton, e altere o atributo *onclick* para *oncomplete*:

```
    <p:column headerText="Ações" style="text-align:center">
        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-check" title="Finalizar" action="#{tarefaBean.setarAtributo(tarefa)}" oncomplete="PF('dlg4').show();" />
        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pause" title="Pausar" action="#{tarefaBean.setarAtributo(tarefa)}" oncomplete="PF('dlg3').show();" />
    </p:column>
```

No seu bean adicione:

```
public synchronized void setarAtributo(Tarefa tarefa) {
    this.setTarefa(tarefa);
}
```

### Algumas observações importantes:

1. Use **actionListener** somente quando seu bean esperar um *event* do JSF. Para chamada de regras de negócio e passagem de atributos procure usar o **action**, como no nosso caso, usando [MethodExpression](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/MethodExpression.html) e EL 2.2 válidos.
2. O atributo que estou passando no action, **tarefa**, deve ser o mesmo usado para iteração, ou seja, o mesmo usado no atributo **var** do seu dataTable.
3. O atributo foi alterado de **onclick** para **oncomplete**, pois isso faz com que componente execute todo o processamento do seu bean, referenciado no action, e somente após processado com sucesso, chamará o código js no *oncomplete* para abrir o dialog.

Answer (score 0):

**Primeiro:**
Criei um objetoSelecionado no seu Bean.

**Segundo:**

```
<p:column >
         <p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('dlg3').show();" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{objeto_que_esta_no_var_datatable}" target="#{SEUBEAN.objetoSelecionado}" />
        </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

**Terceiro:**
Altere seu método `pausarTarefa()`para usar o objetoSelecionado

Este é o primeiro exemplo de Selection no showcase do primefaces, recomendo dar uma olhada para ver qual é o melhor para você, mas essa opção vai resolver seu problema. Segue o [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml).

Comment: Quando eu coloco `pausarTarefa(Tarefa tarefa)` da erro. Quando eu deixo sem funciona, porém o editar fica meio maluco, se eu dou um f5 ele volta pro estado anterior, ou seja com os dados antes da edição

Comment: Você não precisa adicionar um parametro, é só dentro de seu método usar o objetoSelecionado.

Comment: Eu estou usando, porém ele edita se eu dou f5 ele volta pro estado anterior, se eu dou outro f5 ele volta ao editado e assim vai.

Comment: seu bean esta @ViewScoped?

Comment: Sim, tenho que muda-lo?

Comment: Então o problema deve ser no método que preenche a lista da dataTable. Ele não deve estar atualizando a lista ou a dataTable corretamente.

Comment: Eu fiz um `Sysout` pra imprimir a lista no DAO e a cada f5 ele traz uma lista diferente, a atualizada e a antiga. Como isso é possível se no banco de dados está apenas os dados atualizados?

Comment: Bem então seu problema está no seu método ou com você está chamando ele na dataTable, vi que fez outra pergunta vou responder por la, se essa pergunta resolveu seu problema marque-a como correta.